# Attach input type="file" with button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to attach `input type="file"` with a Button and hide the original implementation in react? Pressing the button invokes the file picker with hidden `input type="file"` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using reference. I did it like this:

```
this.uploadRef = React.createRef();
```

```
.chat-image-upload {
  display: none;
}

<input
  type="file"
  ref={(ref) => (this.uploadRef = ref)}
  onChange={this.uploadImage}
  accept="image/*"
  data-field="groupImage"
  className="chat-image-upload"
/>
```

I had an image instead of Button...so can change this accordingly

```
<img
  src={uploadImage}
  className="send-img-img"
  alt="Send"
  onClick={this.imageUploadClick}
/>
```

```
imageUploadClick = () => this.uploadRef.click();
```

```
 uploadImage = async (e) => {
    const fileName = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    if (
      !fileName.endsWith(".jpg") ||
      !fileName.endsWith(".jpeg") ||
      !fileName.endsWith(".gif") ||
      !fileName.endsWith(".png")
    ) {
      alert("Please upload file type image only.");
      return;
    }
    if (e.target.getAttribute("data-field") === "groupImage") {
      const files = e.target.files;
      if (!files.length) {
        return alert("Please choose a file to upload first.");
      } else {
        const file = files[0];
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

> HTML

```
<button type = "button" (click) = "openFile()"></button>
<input type = "file" id = "btnFile"></input>
```

> TypeScript

```
openFile()
{
 document.getElementById("btnFile").click();
}
```